# Replace text only in one part of a page in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, replace

I want to replace a word only in one particular paragraph of a .cs page. I select the paragraph, but when I go to find and replace the text get deselected and the word is highlighted everywhere on the page and not only in that paragraph. Is there a way to achieve what I want in VS or should I just copy the text in another page/text editor and do the replacing there?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the text, press Ctrl+Shift+H, make sure "Selection" is selected in the "Look in" window. While the Find and Replace window is open you should be able to select whatever you want from your code window and the original selection should not change. Copy what you want to replace and paste to Find what window. Set "Replace With" window with the text to replace and click the "Replace All" button.